# setInterval not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, json, setinterval

I have been searching all over the internet tonight, saw a lot of "solutions" but not working for me unfortunately. So I will try to get different answer of what I am seeing here on stack and elsewhere and hoping I will find one which will work...

My page has the following javascript bit:

```
logbook = setInterval(function () {
    $.getJSON("php/log.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {
            $('#logspan').replaceWith(data.logupdate);
        });
    });
}, 5000);
```

When I run the page, it works, but only ONE time and then it stops the interval completely (this is in Chrome and Firefox) and basically gives up.

This is weird, because there is yet another script which is running as follows and is doing its job perfectly:

```
var timer;
function startCount() {
    timer = setInterval(count,1000);
}
function count() {
    var el          = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentNumber   = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
    el.innerHTML        = currentNumber+1;
}
```

I already tried to see if the first script works if I turned the second one off, but it is still no go. So, how can I ever make the first (JSON) script work? It is way past my bedtime thanks to this problem and I haven't gotten any step further!! *pulls hair*

Any suggestions / hints / tips are appreciated...

EDIT: Ok, I found something peculiar, when I replace the "replaceWith" and use "appendTo" it seems to update the #logspan just fine, but obviously I do not want to spam my own webpage. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Your Ajax success callback is replacing the #logspan element with whatever was in the JSON response, so second time in that element doesn't exist unless the JSON content included an element with the same id. Also it seems weird that you'd be doing that replace inside a $.each.

Comment: In the console everything seems ok:
GET http://v.dof-games.net/php/log.php 200 OK 142ms jquery....min.js (regel 140)
GET http://v.dof-games.net/php/log.php 200 OK 127ms jquery....min.js (regel 140)
GET http://v.dof-games.net/php/log.php 200 OK 145ms jquery....min.js (regel 140)

Comment: Why is there `document.getElementById()` in your code when you have jQuery? `var cntr = $('#counter'); cntr.text(parseFloat(cntr.text()) + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed.

1. Use a different variable name than data in your $.each() function body, as you may be inadvertently referring to the data in the $.getJSON() function body
2. Since you're iterating over the posts returned in the JSON call, empty out the body of #logspan only once, then append the content of each post sequentially to #logspan.

   ```
   var logbookTimer = setInterval(function () {  
       $.getJSON("php/log.php", function(data) {  
           // Empty out the body of the log
           $('#logspan').empty();
           // Add some content for each retrieved post
           $.each(data.posts, function(i,d) {  
              $('<div>').html(d.logupdate).appendTo($('#logspan'));  
           });  
       });  
   },5000);
   ```

Comment: What is the difference in using an anonymous function here and a named function?

Comment: setInterval / setTimeout expect 2 params: (1) a reference to a function to execute, or literal code to execute (2) the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. Using literal code is bad practice, because JavaScript will have to reevaluate the function every time the interval runs.

Comment: That's not correct. You cannot distinguish whether a function was passed directly or assigned to a variable first and it does not matter anyways. A function reference is a function reference. I think you confuse this with passing a **string** to `setInterval`.

Comment: @zachelrath: That explanation is wrong. The function statement is executed just once. It would be different if you created an anonymous function *inside* the timer function.

Comment: I edited my initial question, see the EDIT part... which makes this case more interesting. *sigh* ;)

Comment: @zachelrath Ok you got it. The replaceWith was messing with the system here. This is working. Thanks a lot. :D You made my night, and probably the first part of tomorrow morning.

Comment: @FelixKling, you're correct, I was thinking of passing a string.

Comment: @Erik: That was what the first comment on your question was referring to. `replaceWith` will **remove** the element with ID `logspan` from the DOM and subsequent calls will fail. But you didn't seem to bother answering to that...

Comment: I am not a coder, I pick bits and pieces of the internet, with all the techniques going on I miss other bits and pieces which could be relevant. Through my own trial and error I learn, and of course working code. And to be honest, I was looking more at my own code trying to solve it than looking at this stack, I just took the code I saw, implemented it and tested it. Sorry for neglecting all the information here... :/

Comment: @Erik: No worries :) I'm just saying, because that issue could have been resolved quicker and maybe saved you some trouble. Anyways, happy coding!

Comment: Point 1 of this answer is incorrect.  Re-using the variable name "data" in nested functions is confusing for humans reading the code, but Javascript will cope just fine: variable scope is not unpredictable.

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```
var logbook = function () {
    $.getJSON("php/log.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {
            $('#logspan').replaceWith(data.logupdate);
        });
    });
};

setInterval(logbook, 1000);
```

Comment: What's the difference and why should it help? Please do not only post code, also provide an explanation.